# Read and Display XML content in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using Below code for reading a XML file and displaying the details from it on the same screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#xmlButton").click(function() {
            var xmlName = $('input:file').val();
            $("#container").append("File Name:- " + xmlName);
            $.get(xmlName,printData);       
        });

        function printData(data) {
            $(data).find("name").each(function(){
                $("#container").append('<br/>'+$(this).text());
            })
        }
    });
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <h1> Upload XML </h1>
 <form name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" type="Get" action="" >
    <input type="file" name="xmlFile" id="xmlFile">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p><input type="button" name="xmlButton" id="xmlButton" value="Upload"></p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my XMl input file for it is below

```
 <root>
  <info>
    <name>name 1</name>
    <place>Place 1</place>
  </info>
  <info>
    <name>name 2</name>
    <place>Place 2</place>
  </info>
  <info>
    <name>name 3</name>
    <place>Place 3</place>
  </info>
</root>
```

Above code is Working fine in Mozilla Firefox 32 and It is giving below error in Chrome 14 version When I Press Upload button

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/fakepath/test.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP
```

In IE8 It is displaying only File name and no Error message in console.

Is there any other way to get it worked in Chrome and IE? my main purpose is read the xml file and print them in the same screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error occurs because you're trying to do a ajax call for your local file system. Most of the browser will stop the request when you do a cross domain request (a request that aren't in your current domain).
You'll need to upload first submitting the form and when the files is on the server, load with a ajax.

The other way is using HTML5, but your browser need to support it.
More info in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/